# Why isn't my aws cli default region name configuration saving?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I run `aws configure` and am prompted to enter the Default region name, I input `us-east-2` - but it never seems to save that configuration. This feels simple enough, but am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the content of the files in `%UserProfile%/.aws/` after the first attempt to set us-east-2? Wondering if this is a problem with setting or with getting.

Comment: And does your Powershell window have access to the path? It might not for whatever absurd reason so try running as Administrator just in case

Comment: Hmmm, my `%UserProfile/.aws/config` file does actually show us-east-2. What could that mean??

Also, I did try running in Administrator and that doesn't seem to make a difference. I was able to set my credentials at one point, so I'm not sure what could have changed

Answer (score 1):

I found there are 2 files in my `~/.aws/` folder, both of them got a `region` setting in there.

- `config`
- `credentials`

And I modified the `region` in the `credentials` file, then it works to me.